# C++ templates: "type/value mismatch at argument" and "expected a constant type of int, got int"

Tags: c++, templates

I'm new to templates so bear with me...

I am creating a template called "LookUpTable" which takes 2 parameters 'int' and 'class T'.

```
template<int, class T> class LookupTable{
  public:
    LookupTable<int, T> & begin();  //gives both "errors"
    //some more code
};
```

and my definition of the function is:

```
LookupTable <int, T> & LookupTable <int, T> :: begin(){ ... } //gives both "errors".
```

here are the errors/warnings:

```
 error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<int <anonymous>, class T> class LookupTable’
 LookupTable<int, T> & LookupTable<int, T>::begin(){
```

and

```
note:   expected a constant of type ‘int’, got ‘int’
```

I have no idea what is causing this! If I change 'int' to 'const int', it will give a similar error something along the lines "expected ...., got const int". I have searched for a solution but I cannot seem to find anything that can help me in particular.

how can I resolve this? Let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: It expects an integer as the first parameter, so a possible correct instantiation would be `LookupTable<42, double>`. Is it how you intended it to be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're specifying the type `int` as the 1st template argument, but the 1st template parameter is a non-type parameter; which expects some constant expressions with type `int`.

I suppose what you want is to specify the name of the 1st template parameter, then use it as

```
template<int I, class T> class LookupTable{
  public:
    LookupTable<I, T> & begin();
    //some more code
};
```

or

```
template<int I, class T> class LookupTable{
  public:
    LookupTable & begin();
    //some more code
};
```

and define the member function as

```
template<int I, class T>
LookupTable <I, T> & LookupTable <I, T> :: begin(){ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer by @songyunyao:

In case you use the curiously recurring template pattern and the child class (`LookupTable` in this example) has a non-type parameter, you may also have to forward this value to the base class so it can properly refer to the derived class, else you can extract the value of `I` from the child class

```cpp
template <int I, class T, template <Int, class> Child>
LoopkupTableBase {
  Child<I, T> begin(){...}
}

class LookupTable : public LookupTableBase<I, T, LookupTable> {...}
```